# Solution to share Magic Trackpad between Macbook Pro and Windows laptop?

Tags: windows, macbook

I use a Macbook Pro and a Windows Laptop each with its own dedicated monitor. I also have an Apple Magic Trackpad 2 that works great on both Mac and Windows 10. Does anyone know of a solution where the Magic Trackpad can be shared between the two computers without having to manually disconnect from one to move to the other? Essentially a KM switch that would work with the Magic Trackpad 2?

Answer (score 1):

The software solutions [sharemouse](https://www.sharemouse.com/) or [synergy](https://symless.com/synergy) might work for this.
It's not exactly a switch but it virtually connects the computers allowing you to move between the screens as if it was a multi monitor setup.

Comment: Neither of these solutions emulate the magic mouse functionality. They are 3rd party software that use the LAN network to broadcast packets which cause frequent collisions in my experience. I think a hardware solution is more secure.  Thank you for your suggestion however.